# 3D border effect help

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, 3d, borders

can someone please help me and tell me how could I do this border effect in Photoshop?

I know it look like a bad design, but this is an old design of my client and he doesn't have the PSD file anymore.

I searched on Google and other website that I know regarding this, but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried with brevel&embos, with satin and some other tricks, but all I could get is the second img.

If there is someone who knows how to this, please help me.

(first image is the original one, the second one is my version)

[image: Original Image]

[image: My version]

Comment: What technique did you use to create the second one? Giving a little more detail would make your question a lot better

Comment: I'd be willing to bet a substantial amount that the effect was created using AlienSkin Eye Candy (or similar) using a metallic emboss and a rainbow environment map.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a gradient overlay (from the effects panel, not the adjustments) Aset it to soft light. This wil fake shading and give it more of that round feeling.

Answer (score -2):

You can try "Mesh Tool" and "mask" it later on in Illustrator. 
Also it looks like they used a "smudge tool" in Photoshop.